# How to use opencpu.js for calling R function from javascript/jQuery (Using Wampserver)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, wampserver, opencpu

I am trying to use R function dynamically, which means I will be passing parameters from javascript/jQuery. In response, R function should return results dynamically. I am trying to use **opencpu.js** to enable this operation. However, I don't understand, How I can do this with **Wampserver** (as you need to keep everything in www folder)?
Please help.

Comment: OpenCPU works in one of two environments: as a dedicated (unix-based) server or in standalone mode in a local R session (recommended only for dev/test). For dev, it's often convenient to run it as a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/rstudio/).